# Will we transcend language and words in the future?

Tags: language, far-future

Will we transcend language and numbers in the future? I just don't get how this could happen. So would symbols be obsolete too? There would be no fun in art or drawing or making basic symbols. How would any product or tech have a logo if there's only mind communication? That sounds depressing.

*I'm trying to ask this to a user by the name of "kaz" because he has answered something similar before.*

Comment: I cleaned up the text of the question a bit. Can you find the previous post by Kaz and add a link to that to your question, please? That would help provide some context. I tried to do it but, weirdly, we have 2 users named Kaz and a third named Kaz Wolf. More popular than I would have guessed.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15608/kaz. I can't seem to find his old response but he should know what it's about

Comment: Most people would consider humans devolving into speechless animals a rather bleak future.

Comment: What is your definition for a language or numbers? How does mind communication work, if not with a language? How do machines communicate? How far in the future? Do we assume that humans evolve into something or that humans remain the same?

Comment: This sounds like telepathy "if there's only mind communication". No. Symbolic communication will be necessary to keep records. Historical, financial, mathematical models, scientific data, and minutes of meetings are a few examples where records need to be kept.

Comment: Perhaps 'kaz' made a comment that relevant. This makes it harder to find. Hopefully the user is still out there and will see your question.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question. Do you want an explanation for how humanity could develop in such a way that they transcend language? Or do you want a more certain explanation for why they wouldn't? Also, the way you're asking it makes it sound like you're talking more about the real world than a constructed one. Which would make this question off-topic on this site.

Comment: @TreyDill I was going to ping Kaz in chat for you, but since this question is currently on hold I'm not sure what you're looking for.  If this gets reopened, we can try then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Kaz but I'll offer my first impressions all the same. As I see it your question is just:

> Will we transcend language and numbers in the future? ... would symbols be obsolete too?

As social animals humans will always feel the need to communicate (I believe), that communication is currently through written word, speech and body language. These can all be misread and so, in the event a more efficient method arises, I believe they could die out. Some direct transfer of meaning or imagination would surpass them....but this doesn't mean we are living in some bleak future, the pictures and meanings in our minds can be more expressive and colourful than those we can express through a limited selection of words or brush strokes.

If the tech exists for us to record someone's meanings in order to project them as the mental equivalent of a film or book then logos could also be projected and with a deeper meaning behind them.

> There would be no fun in art or drawing or making basic symbols. How would any product or tech have a logo if there's only mind communication? That sounds depressing.

I think perhaps we need to consider the opportunities that this evolution of communication presents, rather than what is lost. We no longer carve words into stone as standard but perhaps at some point someone was mourning this loss in our transition to paper.